# Filter including field in formula

Tags: javascript, filtering, google-cloud-firestore

I want to filter a collection including collection's fields in the criteria.

```
- myCollection
|- name (string)
|- field1 (int)
|- field2 (int)
```

I want to get all names where field1 > field2. I thought it could work this way:

```
db.collection('myCollection').where('field1','>','field2')
  .get().then(function(snapshot){
    //doing something
  });
```

However, it was understood as field1 > 'field2', instead field1 > field2.

I would like to go further, doing something like field1+field2<1000, but both of following queries got no result

```
db.collection('myCollection').where('field1'+'field2','<',1000)
  .get().then(function(snapshot){
    //doing something
  });

db.collection('myCollection').where('field1+field2','<',1000)
  .get().then(function(snapshot){
    //doing something
  });
```

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

There is no way to specify field references in the *value* of an expression.

The best approach I can think of is to store the value of `field2 - field1` in a separate field, so that you can compare that against a constant. E.g. if you store the delta of field2 and field 1 in `delta_field2_field2`, you'd get this query:

```
db.collection('myCollection').where('delta_field2_field2','<', 0)
```

Then if you store the sum of field 1 and 2 in `sum_field1_field2` you'd get:

```
db.collection('myCollection').where('sum_field1_field2','<',1000)
```

You'll see this is a common theme across NoSQL databases: if an operator you want isn't built-in, you can often add data to your model to allow for the use-case.

Comment: For the RTD I like to think about this as a key generation strategy, called it: Composition. In this case, is a document attribute generation strategy.

Comment: That is valid when filter only works on fields, but when filtering is based in combination of parameters and fields it doesn't work. I know NoSQL lacks of it, but I hope Google to considers to work on it.