# Compare two Firestore Timestamps by "greater than"

Tags: firebase, timestamp, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to compare two timestamps inside a cloud function.

Not by "equality" (as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52247134/compare-two-firestore-timestamps-in-cloud-functions)) but by "greater than".

I do not know where is the problem, but I can't get it working.

This is my code, quite simple:

```
 const lastDayUnread = await admin.firestore()
     .collection('/unread')
     .where('last_message', '>', 'last_seen')
     .get()
```

I also tried using .seconds property but still nothing:

```
.where('last_message.seconds', '>', 'last_seen.seconds')
```

If I execute the same query from a JS client, it works, and teh console shows me that there is a Timestamp object inside my documents last_seen and last_message properties.

Comment: why if you are using a timestamp you are using it as an object 'last_message.seconds' ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The right-hand side of a `where` clause in Cloud Firestore must be a literal value. There is no support for looking up the value of another field.

The typical workaround would be to store an additional field with `last_message.seconds - last_seen.seconds` and then:

```
.where('delta_seconds', '>', 0)
```

Comment: I just found that I'd answered this before, so I closed the question as a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49240872/filter-including-field-in-formula/49241166#49241166

Comment: Thank you. I did not know about that behaviour.